# ¿Cómo se escribe la sentencia CREATE TABLE que crea la tabla de destino a partir de un dump SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysqldump

Con un dump MySQL tengo que crear una base de datos MySQL dedicada, importar el dump SQL, que creará la tabla de origen y escribir la sentencia CREATE TABLE para crear la tabla de destino.

Como no tenía una instancia de MySQL en mi máquina he instalado un almacenamiento en Cloud SQL.

Acabo de importar los datos, ¿cómo escribir la sentencia CREATE TABLE que crea la tabla de destino?

Comment: ¿El dump no incluye los objetos? ¿Cómo se creó el dump?

Comment: Y el manual de mysql, que tiene una pagina completa sobre la sentencia create table, no sirve?